# For $f\left(x\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\cos^{2n}\left(x\right)}{n}$, show that $f\left(\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\:=\:ln\left(4\right)$

Tags: calculus, summation

I proved this sum converges in every $x$ except $x=k\cdot 2\pi$, and also proved it is differentiable there.

Now I need to prove the aforementioned claim. With the Pythagorean identity I got to the sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{0.75^n}{n}$, but it doesn't really helps..

Thanks in advance

Comment: **HINT**: think of the Maclaurin series expansion of $\ln(1+x).$

Comment: Convergence actually fails even when $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$, because the powers of $\cos x$ are even. For $\pi\nmid x\in\Bbb R$, $f(x)=-\ln(1-\cos^2x)=2\ln|\csc x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$
for $|x|<1$. Put $x=-\frac{3}{4}$, then we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(3/4)^{n}}{n}=-\ln(1-\frac{3}{4})=\ln4$.